# Command Not Found Using Jenkins Blue Ocean

Tags: go, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

I am trying to set up a Jenkins Blue Ocean pipeline to auto-build my github repo on a PR merge.

I've installed the Go plugins for Jenkins and created the following `Jenkinsfile` with the help of Blue Ocean. Just wanted it to be very simple at first - I have a shell script to run that will build the program I just need Jenkins to run it on merge.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Building Backend') {
      agent any
      steps {
        echo 'Using Go 1.12'
        tool(name: 'Go 1.12', type: 'go')
        echo 'Building Backend...'
        sh 'go version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above Jenkinsfile returns

```
go: command not found
script returned exit code 127
```

but ideally I want it to recognize Go since I will be running a log of `go build` commands. I added Go as a tool in `global tool configuration` in the settings of Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute below command to figure out whether go CLL does exist:

```
sh 'which go'
```

Comment: Unfortunately running that did not work, `returned exit code 1`

Comment: Maybe you should given a specific agent instead of using 'agent any'.

Comment: Could you please give out more log details?

Comment: Thats the most that I get back from blue ocean after the script runs. What would the agent be if it isn't any?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins plugins do not install executables. Think them as controllers. You should install Go into your system and tell Jenkins that the path of the executable in `Global Tool Configuration`.

You can see an example of Git here:

[image: Example of Global Tool Configuration]

Comment: I believe I have set Go as a tool already in the settings, [Here is the screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/zG86H9T)